# Multiple the value from lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

I am trying to multiple the value from this expression (ProductPrice * x):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductPrice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way for you to do that would be to have another property in your model, something like `TotalPrice`:

```
public decimal TotalPrice { get { return ProductPrice * x; } }
```

Then do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => (model.ProductPrice * x))
```